# Excels shows error when trying to convert to PDF through Python

Tags: excel, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a code that would automatically save my excel sheets to PDF and got it to work but with certain files, Excel throws me an error that states "Document not saved. The document may be open, or an error may have been encountered when saving."

I've tried running the same code with other files and it seems to work for about half of them. I've tried to name the file as a different PDF name which still throws the same error for the same files.

```py
import win32com.client as win32

Xlsx = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
Xlsx.Visible = True
wb = Xlsx.Workbooks.Open('Sample')
wb.WorkSheets([3,4,5,6,7,8]).Select()
wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, 'Sample')
wb.Save()
wb.Close()
Xlsx.Quit()
del wb
del Xlsx
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put this as a comment but I don't have enough kudos to do that yet. I would suggest that the issue is probably that some of the files are larger, and for whatever reason the file takes longer to save and therefore there is an issue at the point that the file is being closed (but not yet saved). I think therefore if you put a time pause for a few milliseconds, after the export and/or before the close, it will deal with this.

Initially you could try the following for a one second delay:

import time

time.sleep(1)

If that deals with the issue, you could then decrease to 100 milliseconds with time.sleep(.100) and test again.

Comment: I tried that and it seems that it's still throwing me an error. I tried to run the code up til the ExportAsFixedFormat line and it still throws the same error.

Comment: Is the issue in the Export line?  Do all the workbooks have the same number of sheets?

Comment: The issue happens as the export line. The workbooks don't all have the same number of sheets but they all have enough sheets where the indexing shouldn't have been the issue.